# Resolve a Perfect Sum with Predicate

Tags: c#, logic, predicate

I'm trying to resolve this C# exercise. I can't find the way to do it, even with the suggested tip below.

Make a perfect sum with the following examples:

**Example 1:**

```
Input 1: 5
Input 2: { 9, 6, 3, 12, 7 }
Input 3: 14

Output: 1
```

Explanation:

> Here, the sum of elements `7 + 7 = 14`. Hence, the number of perfect sums in the given array is 1. Therefore, 1 is returned as the output.

**Example 2:**

```
Input 1: 5
Input 2: { 4, 7, 8, 2, 3 }
Input 3: 12

Output: 2
```

Explanation:

> Here, the sum of elements `8 + 4 = 12` and `7 + 3 + 2 = 12`. Hence, the number of perfect sums in the given array is 2. Therefore, 2 is returned as the output.

*I rather like seeing predicate in a function signature. It illustrates that the passed method makes a decision rather than just returns a success code or a different sort of bool.*

Base Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Call the method here
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int PerfectSums(int input, int[] input2, int input3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to need to explain what you are talking about.  After a few false hits (pointing to _perfect numbers_ (which I knew about)), I found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/.  I'm not seeing a relationship between your attempt at explaining things and that web page.  For example, what is the significance of `input 1`?  Why are you allowed to double up the `7`?  If you can double up the 7 in the the first case, why not `2+2+2+2+2+2` or `3+3+3+3` or `4+4+4` or `8+2+2` in the second case

Comment: Hi, I have no more information about that, but I think the "input1" means the size of the array, I've trying to resolve but I think if is lack of information or something that I can't understand, I think if I could catch what the exercise is asking for, it could may be easier to do it.

Comment: In C#, Arrays have a Length property.  You can say `var arr = new int [] {1,2,3};` followed by `var len = arr.Length;` and `len` will be 3

Answer (score 0):

Already solved.

```
static int PerfectSums(int input, int[] input2, int input3)
{
    int count = 0;

    // Loop through each element in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        int remainingSum = input3 - input2[i];

        // Check if there exists another element in the array whose value equals to the remaining sum
        if (Array.Exists(input2, x => x == remainingSum))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```